# input object powershell change

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change the $InvalidInput= $True from a linux to a powershell command. I can run the command through powershell and it tells me that $InvalidInput= $True is true and then comes back false.

I am lost on how to change this. Any information is helpful.

```powershell
$InvalidInput= $true 

         if ( $n -eq 0 ) { 
write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
write-host -n "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(RB/TaxLocator/Cyclic)"
read $ProductionDistroenter code here
       } else {
 $ProductionDistro=$1
       } 
      while { $InvalidInput = $true }
     do
if  ($ProductionDistro = $RB -o $ProductionDistro = $TaxLocator -o $ProductionDistro = $Cyclic) {
    $InvalidInput=$false
        break continue 
        } else { 
            write-host "You have entered an error"
            write-host "You must type RB or TaxLocator or Cyclic"
            write-host "you typed $ProductionDistro"
            write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
            read $ProductionDistro
            }
```

original question asked. ^

The full script will be poseted below so you can see what I am trying to do.

```
function Copy-File {
#.Synopsis
# Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
  param}($TFL09143.pkg,"d/tf90/code_stg","d/tf90bp/code_stg","d/tf90lm/code_stg","d/tf90pv/code_stg")

 # create destination if it's not there ...
 #mkdir $destination -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

 foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) { 
 $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
 while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

   if($original.PSIsContainer) { 
   # mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   # } else {
copy $original.FullName -destination $result
   }
 }
 {$InvalidInput=$true}

   if ( $n -eq 0 ) { 
write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
write-host -n "Which production do you want to run? (RB/TaxLocator/Cyclic)"
 $ProductionDistro
     else 
$ProductionDistro=$1
      }
     ( $InvalidInput = $true) 

if ( $ProductionDistro = $RB,  $ProductionDistro = $TaxLocator, $ProductionDistro = $Cyclic 
            ){
          ( $InvalidInput=$false )
                break 
            } else {
                write-host "You have entered an error"
                write-host "You must type RB or TaxLocator or Cyclic"
                write-host "you typed $ProductionDistro"
                write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
                 $ProductionDistro
            }

    {$InvalidInput=$true}

        if ($n -eq 0) {
            write-host "This script sets up RB TF90 Staging"
            write-host -n "Which Element do you want to run? (TF90/TF90BP/TF90LM/TF90PV/ALL)"
            read $ElementDistro
        else
            $ElementDistro=$1
        }

             ( $InvalidInput = $true )

            If ( $ElementDistro = $TF90, $ElementDistro = $TF90BP, $ElementDistro = $TF90LM, $ElementDistro = $TF90PV, $ElementDistro = $ALL
            ){
                ( $InvalidInput=$false )
                break
            } else {
                write-host "You have entered an error"
                write-host "You must type TF90 or TF90BP or TF90LM or TF90PV"
                write-host "you typed $ElementDistro"
                write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
                $ElementDistro
            } 

if ( $ElementDistro = $TF90 ) {

    cd /d/tf90/code_stg
function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$app03bsi,              #the host name of the SQL server
                [string]$TF90NCS,               #the name of the database
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TF90_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=TF90NCS;Description=TF90NCS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=APP03-
    BSI;DATABASE=TF90NCS;DATASET=DEFAULT"

$Command.CommandType = SET # 1 is the 'Text' command type
$Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

$sqlConnection.Open()
$Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()

if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
      }     
    install -y ../TFL09143.pkg

}

if ( $ElementDistro = $TF90BP ) {
    cd /d/tf90bp/code_stg
    function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$app03bsi,              #the host name of the SQL server
                [string]$TF90BPS,               #the name of the database
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TF90_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=TF90BPS; Description=TF90BPS; Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=APP03-
    BSI;DATABASE=TF90BPS;"

$Command.CommandType = SET # 1 is the 'Text' command type
$Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

$sqlConnection.Open()
$Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()

if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}

    install ../TFL09143.pkg
}

if ( $ElementDistro = $TF90LM ) {
    cd /d/tf90lm/code_stg
    function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$app03bsi,              #the host name of the SQL server
                [string]$TF90LMS,               #the name of the database
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TF90_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=TF90LMS;Description=TF90LMS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=APP03-
    BSI;DATABASE=TF90LMS;"

$Command.CommandType = SET # 1 is the 'Text' command type
$Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

$sqlConnection.Open()
$Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()

if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
    install ../TFL09143.pkg 
}

if ( $ElementDistro = $TF90PV ) {
    cd /d/tf90pv/code_stg
    function Execute-MySQLCommand {param(   [string]$app03bsi,              #the host name of the SQL server
                [string]$TF90PVS,               #the name of the database
                [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]$Command) #the command to execute (name of stored procedure)

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString  = "TF90_CONNECT_STRING=DSN=TF90PVS;Description=TF90PVS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=APP03-
    BSI;DATABASE=TF90PVS;"

$Command.CommandType = SET # 1 is the 'Text' command type
$Command.Connection = $sqlConnection

$sqlConnection.Open()
$Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()

if ($Result -gt 0) {return $TRUE} else {return $FALSE}
}
    install ../TFL09143.pkg
}}}}
```

the out that is produced is 
d/tf90/code_stg
d/tf90bp/code_stg
d/tf90lm/code_stg
d/tf90pv/code_stg
This script sets up TF90 Staging
$InvalidInput=$true
True
You have entered an error
You must type TF90 or TF90BP or TF90LM or TF90PV
you typed 
This script sets up TF90 Staging

after it shows this nothing happens and nothing has been done. My goal is to get it to ask what production i want to choose and let me choose it and also ask what element I want to choose and load the package into the folder. None of this has been done.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly work, as it contains syntactical errors. Please provide a self-contained, working sample that demonstrates the problem. Also provide any error message you're getting.

Comment: The only thing that pops up when running this is      d/tf90/code_stg
d/tf90bp/code_stg
d/tf90lm/code_stg
d/tf90pv/code_stg
This script sets up TF90 Staging
$InvalidInput=$true
True
You have entered an error
You must type TF90 or TF90BP or TF90LM or TF90PV
you typed 
This script sets up TF90 Staging

Comment: I can add the full script that this is part of if that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier way to do this would be to prompt the user for their input, and then do a `While ([User Input] -NotMatch RB or TaxLocator or Cyclic) {Give error and ask again}`. Mind you, that's pseudocode but I think that's going to serve you better than what you're working with. Check this code out:

```
write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
$ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(RB/TaxLocator/Cyclic)"
While($ProductionDistro -notmatch "(RB|TaxLocator|Cyclic)"){
    write-host "`nYou have entered an error" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "You must type RB or TaxLocator or Cyclic"
    write-host "you typed $ProductionDistro"
    write-host "This script sets up TF90 Staging"
    $ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(RB/TaxLocator/Cyclic)"
}
```

Comment: i can add the whole script that the original problem located in so you can everyone can see what i am trying to do. if this will help at all let me know if you want me to do that.

Comment: I don't think it's needed, but in the future posting actual code and not pseudocode would be a good place to start. The code you posted, as Ansgar pointed out, would not function. It has syntax errors to the point of being broken.

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind when posting code. The command runs in linux and I am new to powershell so I had no idea that was pseudocode. Thank you for the information. I posted the original script i am running just so everyone that looks at it can see what I was actually trying to do. once i edit it with the information you gave me I will let you know if that fixes my issues I was having.